# Somar horas com o plugin Final Countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou a fazer um sistema de contagem regressiva e estou a usar ["The Final Countdown jQuery"](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)

```js
$('#clock').countdown('2015/02/16', function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D dias %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mindvelopers.com/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<div id="clock"></div>
```

O meu problema é que preciso de adicionar +21 horas a cada evento (ao resultado), mas não consigo adicionar da forma que esta função é feita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para adicionar horas ao resultado você pode usar [`new Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Você pode usar diretamente o `new Date()` no primeiro parâmetro do `countdown` com um formato mais que seja reconhecido pelo `Date.parse` como o *ISO 8601*, leia em http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15.

Mas se você quiser manter o formato de `string` para facilitar sem necessitar passar um parâmetro mais complexo (como o ISO por exemplo) então você pode usar os sua `string` combinada com `split` e `new Date(ano, mês[, dia[, hora[, minutos[, segundos[, milesegundos]]]]]);`:

```js
    var endIn = '2015/02/16';
    var sumHours = 21;//Soma 21 horas

    var endInV = endIn.split("/");
    var withSum = new Date(endInV[0], endInV[1] - 1, endInV[2]);
    withSum.setHours(withSum.getHours() + sumHours);

    $('#clock').countdown(withSum, function(event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%D dias %H:%M:%S'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mindvelopers.com/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: Na verdade nao está a funcionar correctamente esse codigo. A data este para 2015/02/15, e o resultado está a dizer 6 dias ... e tambem nao está a fazer a contagem decrescente.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria! 
Perfeito. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento +1. Porque você o `split` para criar a data?

Comment: Por que usei o `split` para criar a data ao invés de `new Date(2015, 2, 15)`? Por dois motivos, primeiro para facilitar a adaptação do usuário quanto ao uso do formato `0000/00/00` e por que `new Date(2015, 2, 15)` seria igual a "15 Março 2015" (o correto é Fevereiro, portanto 2 deve ter um -1), outra coisa em alguns navegadores/motores a passagem de string direta como você fez no seu exemplo `new Date ('2015/02/16');` não é um padrão do `ISO`. Obrigado por perguntar :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado pelo comentário =D. Tentei fazer o que você disse e o resultado saiu um pouco diferente do que está nas respostas. Veja [**aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/xmrkb2eg/). Será que a saída desse exemplo não seria a correta?

Comment: @QMechanic73 Ficou muito bom os exemplos, porém ainda sim são mais complexos para os usuários com menor experiencia entenderem. Porém merece +1, principalmente pelo exemplo com ISO :)

Answer (score 1):

Também pode ser feito assim:

```js
var data1 = new Date ('2015/02/16');
var data2 = new Date (data1);
var addHoras = 21;
data2.setHours ( data1.getHours() + addHoras);

$('#clock').countdown(data2, function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D dias %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mindvelopers.com/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<div id="clock"></div>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1nw01q0/1/)</kbd>

Exemplo que segue o formato da [ISO 8601](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```js
var data1 = new Date ('2015-02-16T02:00:00.000Z');
var data2 = new Date (data1);
var addHoras = 21;
data2.setHours ( data1.getHours() + addHoras);

$('#clock').countdown(data2, function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D dias %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mindvelopers.com/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<div id="clock"></div>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9d8dfkf/)</kbd>